# How to access nested parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

In a Controller, I'm trying to access a parameter which is deeply nested. Here is my parameter trace.

`Parameters:`

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2j+Nh5C7jPkNOsQnWoA0wtG/vWxLMpyKt6aiC2UmxgY=",
 "inventory"=>{"ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ingredient_name"=>"Bread"}},
 "purchase_date"=>"11",
 "purchase_price"=>"11",
 "quantity_bought"=>"11"},
 "commit"=>"Create Inventory"}
```

I'm trying to retrieve "Bread" from this. I tried `params[:inventory][:ingredient][:ingredient_name]` and other variations. What is the correct styntax?

If it matters,

`Inventory has_many :ingredients`
`Inventory accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventories`

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083654/elegantly-extracting-all-strings-from-an-arbitrarily-deep-hash - maybe this will help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct access to the value "Bread" would literally be:

```
params[:inventory][:ingredients_attributes]["0"][:ingredient_name]
```

I bet you don't want to do that.

With `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and that hash structure, (also assuming the ingredient attributes are set up correctly), you can set the params on an inventory instance and the value "Bread" would be set as the ingredient_name attribute one of the ingredient objects in the association:

```
@inventory = Inventory.new(params[:inventory]) 
# or @inventory.attributes = params[:inventory] for an existing 
# inventory instance

ingredient = @inventory.ingredients.first
ingredient.ingredient_name
# => "Bread"
```

Comment: I wanted to do your suggested correction, but I had a concern.  I'm writing this code in my `create` action. Will `ingredient = @inventory.ingredients.first` work if I haven't saved @inventory yet?

Comment: Yes, it will work within the request after setting the attributes on the inventory instance, but it won't be persisted unless you successfully call `@inventory.save`.