# How are parameters passed for nested attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have two models, Ingredients and Foods:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :ingredients

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

    attr_accessible :name, :price
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :food

    attr_accessible :ingredient_name, :quantity_used
end
```

The schemas for the two models are as follows:

```
  create_table "foods", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.float   "price"
    t.string  "ingredient_name"
  end

  create_table "ingredients", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "ingredient_name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "food_id"
    t.integer "quantity_used"
  end
```

I'm creating a form for Food which also creates/updates the Ingredient table as well. I have the form working, and the submit button updates the correct attributes, but I have other attributes in each table that I want to update as well. For example, in the Food Controller, I want to do something like `ingredient.user_id = current_user.id`. I understand I can access things through params[:food], but how do I access individual fields which aren't being updates by the form?

Right now, my form is:

```
<%= form_for(@food) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label "Ingredient Used:" %>
        <%= builder.text_field :ingredient_name %><br />
            <%= builder.label "Quantity Used:" %>
            <%= builder.text_field :quantity_used %><br />
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I access this specific Food's ingredients in the Food#create action?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to your earlier question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073617/how-to-access-nested-parameters-in-rails. Also, have a look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: The answer there didn't work for me originally. Looking back, I had a typo, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add **:ingredients_attributes** to **attr_accessible** in your Food model.

You can mess about with the params hash in the controller by iterating over the **:ingredients_attributes** or you can use [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes).